# Magento Migration Tool mapping files for config.xml

Tags: migration, mapping

So I am configuring the Magento Migration Tool as a separate module, as recommended in the documentation. I have followed all the instructions and got to the point of providing some table ignores within the map.xml file I moved to the module. I'm happy that is fine and have updated the location within config.xml, once again in the module.

I don't need to do any other "excludes" or "transforms" etc... so I don't need to edit any further XML files for mapping. However, in config.xml there are a number of other files mentioned, with the .dist extension, which I have NOT moved to the module. Even if not editing these files am I required to move them to the module like I have done with map.xml? Do I just delete the entries I am not editing from the config file? The extract I am talking about is as follows:

```
    <options>
      <map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.4.5/map.xml</map_file>
      <eav_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-eav.xml.dist</eav_map_file>
      <eav_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/eav-document-groups.xml.dist</eav_document_groups_file>
      <eav_attribute_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/eav-attribute-groups.xml.dist</eav_attribute_groups_file>
      <log_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-log.xml.dist</log_map_file>
      <log_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/log-document-groups.xml.dist</log_document_groups_file>
      <settings_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/settings.xml.dist</settings_map_file>
      <customer_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-customer.xml.dist</customer_map_file>
      <customer_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/customer-document-groups.xml.dist</customer_document_groups_file>
      <customer_attribute_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/customer-attribute-groups.xml.dist</customer_attribute_groups_file>
      <delta_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/deltalog.xml.dist</delta_document_groups_file>
      <order_grids_document_groups_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/order-grids-document-groups.xml.dist</order_grids_document_groups_file>
      <map_document_groups>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-document-groups.xml.dist</map_document_groups>
      <class_map>etc/opensource-to-opensource/class-map.xml.dist</class_map>
      <tier_price_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.4.5/map-tier-price.xml.dist</tier_price_map_file>
      <stores_map_file>etc/opensource-to-opensource/map-stores.xml.dist</stores_map_file>
```

Any advice is much appreciated. I don't want to finish up the config for the Migration Tool and run it without being sure I've set-up the files in the right place etc...

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clear your questions what want you .

Comment: I want to know whether I need to either:
- copy across the .dist referenced files
or
- comment out/delete the references to all the files I don't wish to change

Comment: i am suggest to the you don't delete any .dist extension file because magento use all file in migration time.So you onlt remove .dist extention

Comment: I am not sure you follow what I am asking here, or at least I'd like to check you do.

I have created the module according the the section "Configure migration in a separate module" on this page:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/migration-tool-configure.html
I have then copied the map.xml.dist to the correct location within the new module and renamed it map.xml
I don't want to add any further bespoke migration configurations. I have not copied over any of the other files listed in the config to the new module. 
Either I need to or I remove the config associated?

Comment: So I have resolved this - I think I misread a bit of the advice and guidance, hence why I was confused.